# Jquery Ajax post to MVC controller does not work (returns null)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

my ajax post to controller does not work. The code below is a basic example of what I am trying to do.

On debug mode, it returns null and the values returned to the ajax call is empty, even if I appened the attribute

```
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]Data data)
```

It still does not work

Here is my ajax all

```
$('#SignIn').click(function () {
    $('#SignIn').val('Please Wait');            
    Ajax_Login();
});

function Ajax_Login() {           
    var data = {
        username: $('#Email').val().trim(),
        password: $('#Password').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Upload/Login",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (message) {
            alert(message);             
        },
        error: function (message) {
            alert(message);  
        }
```

I have also tried using `data: JSON.stringfy({ User: Username, Pass: Password })`

Here is my controller

```
public class Data
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(Data data)
{
    var message = data.Username + " and " + data.Password;
    return Json(message);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json",` ajax option.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. When do you use contentType ? when its stringfy ? and how do I mark this as answer ? thank you

Comment: You should never need to use `contentType: "application/json"` in mvc if you have generated your view correctly. But if you did have that option, then you would also have needed `data: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: And if you have generated you view correctly then you would not even need your `var data = { ... };` code - it would be just `data = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: And I need some sleep, so feel free to add your own answer if you want.

Comment: I see, thanks for your advise, also how do I mark this as an answer ?

Comment: I wish I could, but I cant take the glory for what you have done. When you wake up, pls do and then I will mark as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sending an object in the request, so you need to remove the `contentType: "application/json",` option in in ajax function so that it uses the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.

Alternatively (if you do use `'application/json'`), you need to stringify your object using `data: JSON.stringify(data),`. However, in mvc you should rarely have to use those options if you have generated the view correctly by strongly binding to your model, for example using `<input asp-for="Username" />` or `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)`. When the view is generated correctly, then you can simply use `var data = $(yourForm).serialize();` to correctly serialize all the form controls.

Note that the reason that `JSON.stringfy({User: Username, Pass: Password})` did not work is because your model does not contain properties named `User` and `Pass`.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Hi, Ehi. I red everything and tried everything but it doesn't work for me. What is your final solution for your controller method and ajax data?